# How to unpack first-class module to module for object with class declaration?

Tags: class, object, ocaml, unpack

I have:

```
module type A = sig end
```

This code is valid:

```
let f x = 
  let module X = (val x : A) in
  object end
```

and this:

```
let f (module X : A) = 
  object end
```

But this is invalid:

```
class c x = 
  let module X = (val x : A) in
  (*              ^^^ Error: Syntax error *)
  object end
```

and this:

```
class c (module X : A) = 
(*       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: Modules are not allowed in this pattern. *)
  object end
```

And I can not understand: Why?
How to unpack first-class module to module for object in class context?
My compiler version = 4.01.0

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any form of local module for a class definition is not allowed:

```
class c =
    let module L = List in
      object end;;
    Characters 18-24:
      let module L = List in
          ^^^^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

I'm not certain of the exact reason, but I have it [on very good authority](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6271#c10745) that it would be very difficult to implement.

However, it is possible to accept a first-class module argument to a class and unpack it within the methods and values that actually use it. For example:

```
class c d = object
  method foo =
    let module D = (val d : A) in
      D.b + 5
end
```